# Does Android 4.0.3 support SIP?

Tags: android, sip, voip

If yes then why `SipManager.isApiSupported()`, `SipManager.isVoipSupported()` returns `false`? Is there anything to be done to make it Sip supported? I have tried those codes in the emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it's up to the device. Not all devices support the SIP APIs.

`SipManager.isApiSupported()` returns false if the device doesn't support SIP at all, while `SipManager.isVoipSupported()` returns false if it does not support the SIP based VoIP APIs.

It's up to your code to verify that the device supports the APIs before using them, and possibly offer a workaround/alternative for devices that don't.

There's of course nothing really stopping you from adding your own SIP stack to your application, these APIs will only tell you if it's *built in*.

Comment: @juned Yes, if you include your own SIP stack, your application can use it on any device. Note though that many cell phone networks (most likely the same networks that disallow a built in SIP stack in the phone) block VoIP network traffic so you may still have problems.